# Too high latency of detectIntent() api of dialogflow v2 using node library

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

I am trying to call the detectIntent() of v2 api of dialogflow using node library. But, i am getting around average 1.5 sec delay in response, which is too high as compared to v1 api's which are too fast. This is affecting the user experience of chatbot.
Library:- https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2

A code snippet for testing **detectIntent()** api of node library adopted from getting started sample of library and which logs api response time.

```js
// You can find your project ID in your Dialogflow agent settings
const projectId = '<project-id-here>';
const sessionId = 'fa2d5904-a751-40e0-a878-d622fa8d65d9';
const query = 'hi';
const languageCode = 'en-US';
const credentials = {
  client_email: '<client-email-here>',
  private_key:
    '<private-key-here>',
};
// Instantiate a DialogFlow client.
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');

const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
  projectId,
  credentials,
});

// Define session path
const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);

// The text query request.
const request = {
  session: sessionPath,
  queryInput: {
    text: {
      text: query,
      languageCode,
    },
  },
};
const st = new Date();
console.log('Start Time : ', st.toISOString());
// Send request and log result
sessionClient
  .detectIntent(request)
  .then(responses => {
    const et = new Date();
    console.log('End Time : ', et.toISOString());
    console.log('Duration : ', (et - st) / 1000);

    console.log('Detected intent');
    const result = responses[0].queryResult;
    console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
    console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);
    if (result.intent) {
      console.log(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`  No intent matched.`);
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

Sample output is:-

```
Start Time :  2018-05-16T12:30:15.012Z
End Time :  2018-05-16T12:30:17.221Z
Duration :  2.209
Detected intent
  Query: hi
  Response: 
  Intent: intent_general_greetings
```

In output, duration is in seconds. So, we are getting api response around **1-2 secs.**

Can somebody help in understanding the issue, why we are getting too much high latency. I have good internet. I also tested above code snippet on aws ec2. Still, getting that much latency in calls.

Is this the performance of dialogflow of v2 api's ?

Comment: I am migrating to v2, and I notice the same drop in performance, I didn't have the time to debug it yet.

Comment: Same here. Just to pass through `new dialogflow.SessionsClient()` takes 1387.8ms from a Firebase function.

Comment: Has anyone figured this one out? I'm having the same kind of latency. Just calling `sessionClient.detectIntent` takes over 1s